# using jquery to make a html canvas fluid based on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Is it possible to make an HTML5 canvas width and height fluid based on the current windows dimensions? ..With jQuery, within a window.resize() function? If so I'm just looking for a super basic example.  I've been trying to research this all morning, but haven't found a solid answer on the topic.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Well... the canvas is as any other HTML element and can be styled with CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/ha73R/ . What exactly weren't you able to achieve?

Comment: No I don't want to use percentages.  I wan to capture the actual demensions and load in the numbers based on window resize.  Reason being - the plugin I am using (which dynamically generates a canvas to the DOM) does not take percentages.  Other than that, I totally agree with you Cristy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is very easy to do:

```
   $(window).resize(function () { 
       $('#canvas').width($(window).width());
       $('#canvas').height($(window).height());
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ha73R/1/